Determining image location in Listbox
I'm having problems with the image location in listbox. I want to show an image under the text, but the image appears over the text. Can you help me with this?
I am trying to place the image under the additional text but it appears over it.
private void listBoxQuestions_MeasureItem(object sender, MeasureItemEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBoxItem item = listBoxQuestions.Items[e.Index] as ComboBoxItem;

    if (item != null)
    {
        string questionText = item.Text;

        using (Graphics g = e.Graphics)
        {
            // ListBox'ın mevcut genişliğine göre metnin sığmasını sağlamak için ölçüm yapıyoruz
            int itemWidth = listBoxQuestions.Width - 30; // Kenarlık payı için biraz boşluk bırakıyoruz
            SizeF textSize = g.MeasureString(questionText, listBoxQuestions.Font, itemWidth);

            // Yüksekliği, ölçülen metin yüksekliğine göre dinamik olarak ayarlıyoruz
            e.ItemHeight = (int)Math.Max(30, textSize.Height + 2); // Minimum 30px, metnin boyutuna göre artırıyoruz
        }
    }

}

private void listBoxQuestions_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Index < 0) return;

    // ListBox'taki öğeler arasında gezinip ComboBoxItem'ları kontrol ediyoruz
    if (listBoxQuestions.Items[e.Index] is ComboBoxItem item)
    {
        // Başlık olan item'lar için seçilebilirliği kontrol ediyoruz
        if (!item.Selectable)
        {
            // Kazanım adı (İlgili Kazanım) için mavi ve bold font kullanılıyor
            if (item.Text.StartsWith("İlgili Kazanım"))
            {
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, e.Bounds); // Arka plan rengi
                e.Graphics.DrawString(item.Text, new System.Drawing.Font(e.Font, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Blue, e.Bounds); // Kazanım adı yazı rengi ve font stili
            }
            else if (item.Text.StartsWith("--")) // Başlık metnini kontrol ediyoruz
            {
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, e.Bounds); // Arka plan rengi
                e.Graphics.DrawString(item.Text, new System.Drawing.Font(e.Font, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, e.Bounds); // Başlık yazı rengi ve font stili
            }
            else
            {
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, e.Bounds); // Arka plan rengi
                e.Graphics.DrawString(item.Text, e.Font, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds); // Diğer öğeler için siyah yazı rengi
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Normal öğeler için çizim işlemi
            e.DrawBackground();  // Başka bir seçim durumu varsa arka planı çiz

            // Checkbox alanı
            System.Drawing.Rectangle checkboxRect = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(e.Bounds.Left + 5, e.Bounds.Top + 5, 12, 12);
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, checkboxRect);
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, checkboxRect);

            // Eğer işaretliyse, bir tik işareti çiz
            if (item.IsChecked)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawString("✔", e.Font, Brushes.Black, checkboxRect.Left + 1, checkboxRect.Top + 1);
            }

            // **Resmin Gösterimi**
            string imagePath = item.Value as string;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(imagePath) && File.Exists(imagePath))
            {
                try
                {
                    // Resmi yükle ve uygun boyutlara getir
                    Image img = Image.FromFile(imagePath);

                    // Resmi, metnin sol tarafına ekle
                    int imageWidth = 40;
                    int imageHeight = (int)((float)img.Height / img.Width * imageWidth); // Resmi orantılı şekilde boyutlandır

                    // Resmi çizin
                    e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, e.Bounds.Left + 20, e.Bounds.Top + 5, imageWidth, imageHeight);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // Resim yükleme hatası
                    MessageBox.Show("Resim yüklenemedi: " + ex.Message);
                }
            }

            // **Metni Gösterme**
            // Sorunun metnini checkbox'ın sağında çiziyoruz
            e.Graphics.DrawString(item.Text, e.Font, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds.Left + 30, e.Bounds.Top + 5); // Metni resmin sağında çiz
        }
    }

    e.DrawFocusRectangle(); // Seçim vurgusunu çizer
}
public void LoadQuestions(List<int> selectedRids)
{
    // Öncelikle listBoxQuestions içindeki tüm kontrolleri (resimler gibi) temizleyelim
    foreach (Control control in listBoxQuestions.Controls)
    {
        if (control is PictureBox pictureBox)
        {
            listBoxQuestions.Controls.Remove(pictureBox); // Resmi kaldır
            pictureBox.Dispose(); // Bellekten temizle
        }
    }

    listBoxQuestions.Items.Clear(); // Listeyi temizle
    string previousTitle = ""; // Başlıkları karşılaştırmak için
    string previousAdditionalText = ""; // Aynı açıklama metninin tekrar eklenmesini engellemek için
    string previousKazanımAdi = ""; // Kazanım adının tekrarlanmaması için

    using (SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();

        foreach (int kid in selectedRids)
        {
            SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(
                "SELECT sorular.soru, sorutip.baslik, sorumetni.metin, sorumetni.resim_yolu, kazanimlar.kadi FROM sorular " +
                "LEFT JOIN sorutip ON sorular.tid = sorutip.tid " +
                "LEFT JOIN sorumetni ON sorular.sid = sorumetni.sid " +
                "LEFT JOIN kazanimlar ON sorumetni.kid = kazanimlar.kid " +
                "WHERE sorumetni.kid = @kid ORDER BY sorutip.baslik", connection);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kid", kid);
            SQLiteDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                string questionTitle = reader["baslik"].ToString();
                string additionalText = reader["metin"] != DBNull.Value ? reader["metin"].ToString() : "";
                string imagePath = reader["resim_yolu"] != DBNull.Value ? reader["resim_yolu"].ToString() : "";
                string questionText = reader["soru"].ToString();

                // Kazanım adı kontrolü
                string kazanımAdi = reader["kadi"] != DBNull.Value ? reader["kadi"].ToString() : "Bilinmiyor"; // Eğer "kadi" null ise "Bilinmiyor" yazsın.

                // Başlıkları ekliyoruz, ancak bunlara checkbox eklemiyoruz
                if (questionTitle != previousTitle)
                {
                    // Kazanım adı daha önce eklenmediyse ekliyoruz
                    if (kazanımAdi != previousKazanımAdi)
                    {
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(previousKazanımAdi))
                        {
                            // Önceki kazanım eklenmişse, araya boş satır ekliyoruz
                            listBoxQuestions.Items.Add(new ComboBoxItem
                            {
                                Text = "", // Boş satır
                                Value = "",
                                Selectable = false, // Seçilemez
                                IsChecked = false    // Checkbox'lı değil
                            });
                        }

                        listBoxQuestions.Items.Add(new ComboBoxItem
                        {
                            Text = $"İlgili Kazanım : {kazanımAdi}", // Kazanım adı
                            Value = "",
                            Selectable = false, // Seçilemez
                            IsChecked = false    // Checkbox'lı değil
                        });

                        previousKazanımAdi = kazanımAdi; // Kazanım adını kaydediyoruz
                    }

                    // Başlık metnini ekliyoruz
                    listBoxQuestions.Items.Add(new ComboBoxItem
                    {
                        Text = $"-- {questionTitle}", // Başlık
                        Value = "",
                        Selectable = false, // Başlıklar seçilemez
                        IsChecked = false  // Başlıklar checkbox'lı değil
                    });

                    previousTitle = questionTitle;
                    previousAdditionalText = ""; // Başlık değiştiğinde açıklamayı sıfırla
                }

                // **Açıklama Metnini (additionalText) ekleme**
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(additionalText) && additionalText != previousAdditionalText)
                {
                    listBoxQuestions.Items.Add(new ComboBoxItem
                    {
                        Text = additionalText,
                        Value = additionalText,
                        Selectable = false,  // Açıklamalar seçilemez
                        IsChecked = false    // Checkbox'lı değil
                    });
                    previousAdditionalText = additionalText; // Eklenen açıklamayı kaydediyoruz
                }

                // **Resim ekleme**: Eğer resim yolu varsa, resmi ekliyoruz
                string baseDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory; // Dinamik çalışma dizini
                string imageDirectory = Path.Combine(baseDirectory, "resimler"); // Resim klasörü
                string imageFileName = reader["resim_yolu"].ToString(); // Veritabanından gelen dosya adı
                string resim = Path.Combine(imageDirectory, imageFileName); // Tam dosya yolu oluştur

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(resim) && File.Exists(resim))
                {
                    // Resim için PictureBox oluşturuluyor
                    PictureBox pictureBox = new PictureBox
                    {
                        Image = Image.FromFile(resim),
                        SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage,
                        Height = 50,  // Resim yüksekliği
                        Width = 50,   // Resim genişliği
                        Margin = new Padding(5, 10, 5, 15)
                    };

                    // Resmi listeye ekliyoruz (listBox yerine FlowLayoutPanel veya benzeri bir kontrol kullanılabilir)
                    listBoxQuestions.Controls.Add(pictureBox);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Resim bulunamadı: " + resim); // Resim bulunamadığında hata mesajı
                }

                // **Soru metnini (questionText) ekleme**
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(questionText)) // Eğer soru metni boş değilse
                {
                    listBoxQuestions.Items.Add(new ComboBoxItem
                    {
                        Text = questionText,
                        Value = questionText,
                        Selectable = true,  // Sorular seçilebilir
                        IsChecked = false   // Başlangıçta checkbox işaretli değil
                    });
                }
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
    }
}

I want to place the image as in the picture.](https://i.sstatic.net/YFeMhzax.jpg)

What kind of Controls are you working with? -- Remove this: using (Graphics g = e.Graphics), that's not yours to dispose of -- Read the notes here: How to add multiline Text to a ListBox item? about the height of a ListBox item -- A (WinForms) ListBox is probably not the right Control for the task at hand

For example, this instead: Image img = Image.FromFile(imagePath); is an object you generated, that you need to take care of (dispose of it) -- Out of curiosity, has the code above (even partially) been written by an AI of sort?

Please reduce the code to the minimal neccessary. Your non-english comments and naming distract or at least does not help understanding what you are doing here. Example you add pitcureboxes and paint images yourself. What image do we see in your screenshot? Why both?

Yes, it was written by artificial intelligence.. I am not sure about the controls.

Then change AI tool, that one doesn't know what it's writing. WPF and WinForms are also mixed in a completely incompatible way. Bugs, redundancies and leaks everywhere. For starters, you could take the code you find in the post I've linked and adapt it, if it's possible in your scenario. Read the notes there. Or move to WPF entirely, then you have a different story to write

I am using winfowm. I cannot change it.

Then use it! And remove all parts related to WPF. These two GUI platforms cannot be mixed here
